# Как можно использовать функцию до её объявления в kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Мне нужно вызвать в теле функции другую, которая объявлена ниже, как это можно сделать, напрмер в python я бы написал: global <имя функции>

Comment: Кстати, не понял пример из питона - global там используется для переменных. Каким образом вы его применяете к функциям?

Comment: Если функция объявлена ниже, просто вводишь в другой функции global <название> и она работает независимо от положения

Comment: не работает. Это у вас какой-то другой питон.

Answer (score 2):

Как и ту, которая объявлена выше. В котлине порядок объявления функций не имеет значения.

Comment: Но у меня она выделяется, как несуществующая

Comment: Значит, нужно предоставить код.

Comment: Проблему решил, зачем-то объявлял все функции внутри main

Comment: как это не имеет значения: https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjYxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cblxuZnVuIG1haW4oYXJnczogQXJyYXk8U3RyaW5nPikge1xuXG4vLyAgICAgZ3JlZXRGdW5jdGlvbigpIC8vIGVycm9yXG4gICAgXG4gICAgZnVuIGdyZWV0RnVuY3Rpb24oKSB7XG4gICAgICAgIHByaW50bG4oXCJIZWxsb1wiKVxuXHR9XG4gICAgZ3JlZXRGdW5jdGlvbigpIC8vb2tcblxufVxuXG5cblxuXG4ifQ==

Comment: @qwabra Это немного другое. Вот: https://pl.kotl.in/2v2T_pDbT

Comment: стоп, вы же говорите про весь язык. что в рамках языка последовательность не имеет значение, и с этим я не согласен. тут ваш пример скорее исключение, и в рамках языка оно как раз наоборот, как вижу я.

Comment: @qwabra исключение скорее ваш пример, потому что в main функции как правило не определяют.

Comment: давайте предположим что это не мейн а коннект ф-я. а потом ещё вспомним до кучи про лямбды.

Comment: @qwabra Я отвечал на конкретный вопрос в рамках этого вопроса. Можете дополнить, если есть желание. Или поставить минус. Или написать свой ответ.